# WildFly Could not find resource for full path (No XML, using CLI Deployment)

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I've been reading threads on SO about this for a while, but I can't figure out whether this is a WildFly deployment issue or a RESTEasy issue. Any help would be appreciated.

When I try to access: `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/json/hi`

Error message:

```
12:27:04,159 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/json/hi
```

`JAXActivator.java`:

```java
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;
    
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
    
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JAXActivator extends Application { }
```

`web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    
    <display-name>hello</display-name>
</web-app>
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Start Page</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Hello World WOO!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`HelloWorld.java`:

```java
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;
    
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    
public class HelloWorld {
    //@Inject
    //HelloService helloService;
    
    @GET
    @Path("/json/{p}")
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("p") String param) {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + param + "\"}";
        //return "{\"result\":\"" + helloService.createHelloMessage(param) + "\"}";
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/xml/{p}")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public String getHelloWorldXML(@PathParam("p") String param) {
        return "<xml><result>" +param+ "</result></xml>";
        //return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage(param) + "</result></xml>";
    }
}
```

My directory structure:
[image: pic to show my directory directory structure]

WildFly server commands:

Terminal 1:

`/etc/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh`

Terminal 2:

`/etc/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="deploy --force /home/king/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/target/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't obvious but I've never been able to have static content on the same path at JAX-RS content.  Change your `JAXActivator.java` file to have a path like `/rest` or whatever you'd like.  Ultimately when a request comes in Wildfly needs to determine how to route it.  As you have it now your services start at `/` but so does the static content.  Partition your URL space between services and static and you won't run into this issue.

**EDIT:**

Weird - I copied you code directly and am running under Ubuntu also.  I've got a totally fresh Wildfly 10.1.0.Final.  If I use your code as is I too get a 404.  But if I put a @Path annotation on the class:

```
package com.sentiment360.helloworld;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Path("/json/{p}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public String getHelloWorldJSON(@PathParam("p") String param) {
        return "{\"result\":\"" + param + "\"}";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/xml/{p}")
    @Produces({"application/xml"})
    public String getHelloWorldXML(@PathParam("p") String param) {
        return "<xml><result>" + param + "</result></xml>";
    }
}
```

and include that path in the URL it works fine.  I'll admit I always have that extra class level Path on my services to help scope them but I didn't think it was required.  I'll have to learn some more.

**EDIT 2:**

Well, I learned something - the "root resource" declaration (a.k.a. the @Path at the class level) is required.  This is why my IDE was telling me that the class was unused when I didn't have it.  I've always done it this way but never know that it was required.  Between the @ApplicationPath and the @Path at the class level it was all working as expected.

Comment: @Rilcon42 check "edit2" as well (though I guess it really should be its own answer)

Comment: Cant thank you enough man, I have been beating my head against that for a while

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

- It seems you did not register you REST service.
- Did not configure servlet in `web.xml`.

There two ways to configure REST service:

- Register in `Application` class.
- Using `@Path` annotation.

You refer to this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/)

---

> Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT/json/hi

I think the web container treats this URL as a static page instead of servlet. So you the corresponding REST path(/json/hi) will not get the request.

Comment: That tutorial is from 2011 - you haven't had to configure anything in web.xml for quite some time now.

Comment: I've not checked the year it published. I think it doesn't matter, only if the theory of both scenarios are the same.